# javascript parse promises - updating records

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm new to javascript, and promises, and am having a hard time groking this one.

What I need to do is search for a set of records.  Once I have them, loop through and add up the values of a field in each record.  That value is then used in conjunction with a passed in value to calculate what the new value should be for each record.  So essentially what I'm doing is:

```
    var paymentQuery = new Parse.Query("MemberPayment");
    paymentQuery.equalTo("type", type);
    paymentQuery.find().then(
        function(payments) {
            var totalPaidIn = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
                var payment = payments[i];
                totalPaidIn += payment.get("amountPaidIn");
            }

            // Total the amount 
            var unitValue = 100.0/totalPaidIn;
            unitValue = unitValue.toFixed(3);

            for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
                var payment = payments[i];
                var paidIn = payment.get("amountPaidIn");
                var new = Math.round(((paidIn * unitValue) / 100) * amountPassedIn);
                payment.set("amountPaidOut", paidIn + new);
                payment.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
            }
        }
    )
```

Basically, what I need here is synchronous saves.  Because I'm getting a value from the record, updating it, and then saving.  What I'm seeing is that if I have two sets of three records, i.e. this code gets called twice, and my original value of amountPaidIn is 0 in each record, then both times through the second loop, I'm getting a value of 0.  So the first save doesn't seem to have taken place by the time I'm going through the loop a second time.

So I'm just not getting how this is supposed to look using promises?

**EDIT:**

I neglected to add that this all takes place in a loop.

**UPDATE:**

dan, I copied your code exactly as it is, aside from passing in a numerical value, not a type, like so:

```
function updateAllPayments() {
    var amounts = [ 1000, 2000, 3000 ];
    var promises = amounts.map(function(amountWon) {
        return updatePaymentsWithAmount(amountWon);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}
```

I put a log statement before we add each promise:

```
var payment = payments[i];
var paidIn = payment.get("amountPaidIn");
var paidOut = payment.get("amountPaidOut");
var add = Math.round(((paidIn * unitValue) / 100) * amountWon);
payment.set("amountPaidOut", paidOut + add);
console.log("before savepromise add is " + add + " paid in " + paidIn + " paid out " + paidOut);
var savePromise = payment.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
promises.push(savePromise);
```

This is the output:

```
amount won is 3000
before savepromise add is 1286 paid in 15 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 857 paid in 10 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 857 paid in 10 paid out 0
amount won is 1000
before savepromise add is 429 paid in 15 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 286 paid in 10 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 286 paid in 10 paid out 0
amount won is 2000
before savepromise add is 857 paid in 15 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 571 paid in 10 paid out 0
before savepromise add is 571 paid in 10 paid out 0
```

And the final values in the database are:

```
857
286
571
```

So it still appears that the queries are running asynchronously, and all 3 queries start before any of the saves get executed.

Comment: `what I need here is synchronous saves` - if `payment.save` is asynchronous, then you want the impossible

Comment: I'm surprised your code runs at all, with `var new = ...`

Comment: I think the question should be edited to indicate that the posted code is also called in a loop.  I've updated my answer to account for the new context.  You can delete the long comment below posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.when covers this case really well.  It resolves when all of the promises passed to it resolve.

**EDIT** the OP has provided additional context:  the find, also, is part of a loop.  Problems like this can usually be helped by a little additional abstraction.

Let's put my original advice in a function body, call it `updateMemberPaymentsWithType`...

```
function updateMemberPaymentsWithType(type) {
    var paymentQuery = new Parse.Query("MemberPayment");
    paymentQuery.equalTo("type", type);
    paymentQuery.find().then(function(payments) {
        var totalPaidIn = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
            var payment = payments[i];
            totalPaidIn += payment.get("amountPaidIn");
        }

        // Total the amount 
        var unitValue = 100.0/totalPaidIn;
        unitValue = unitValue.toFixed(3);

        var promises = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
            var payment = payments[i];
            var paidIn = payment.get("amountPaidIn");
            var new = Math.round(((paidIn * unitValue) / 100) * amountPassedIn);
            payment.set("amountPaidOut", paidIn + new);
            var savePromise = payment.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
            promises.push(savePromise);
        }
        // now promises is an array of save promises
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    });
}
```

Notice how it returns the promise created by Promise.when().  Now you have a promise-returning function that can be used elsewhere, including calling it from a loop, like this:

```
function updateAllPayments() {
    var types = [ "typeA", "typeB", "typeC" ];
    var promises = types.map(function(type) {
        return updateMemberPaymentsWithType(type);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}
```

Notice how this one also collects promises, and returns a promise to resolve all of them.  You can use this style to build arbitrarily complex combinations of async operations with very clear, testable code.  Ultimately in Parse, some cloud function will want to call it like this....

```
Parse.Cloud.define("someCloudFunction", function(request, response) {
    updateAllPayments().then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run asynchronous code "sequentially", you can do it quite easily using promises - promise chaining is the key

```
var paymentQuery = new Parse.Query("MemberPayment");
paymentQuery.equalTo("type", type);
paymentQuery.find().then(
    function(payments) {
        var totalPaidIn = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
            var payment = payments[i];
            totalPaidIn += payment.get("amountPaidIn");
        }

        // Total the amount 
        var unitValue = 100.0/totalPaidIn;
        unitValue = unitValue.toFixed(3);
        var promise = Promise.resolve(); // an initial promise tp start the chain
        for (var i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
            var payment = payments[i];
            var paidIn = payment.get("amountPaidIn");
            var add = Math.round(((paidIn * unitValue) / 100) * amountPassedIn);
            payment.set("amountPaidOut", paidIn + add);
            // chain the requests so they run one after the other
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                return payment.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
            });
        }
        return promise;
    }
).then(function() {
    // at this point all payments are saved
});
```

Of course, the above assumes `payment.save` returns a `promise` - I also changed `var new` to `var add` because the code in the question is actually invalid